# Numpy.genfromtxt() returning NaN when importing zeroes

Tags: python, numpy, nan

So I have an array which looks like this:

```
0.00,69.54
58.00,69.69
103.00,69.72
345.00,69.80
398.00,70.03
427.00,70.31
```

in a .csv file. I want to plot first column (x) versus second column (y). When I import the data and plot it using Numpy's `genfromtxt` the first point doesn't show. Sure enough when I print the arrays it returns the first x value (should be 0) as `nan`. Why is this?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cTime, gObs = np.genfromtxt('drift.csv', delimiter=',', unpack = True)

print(cTime)
```

`print(cTime)` returns: `[ nan  58. 103. 345. 398. 427.]` but the first value in my list is zero. What is happening?

Comment: "looks somewhat like this" isn't good enough. Show us the actual contents of the file. If that's too much data, make a smaller file, rerun the code on the smaller file, and rewrite your post in terms of the smaller file.

Comment: Did you notice that the values yu have in your list are totally different than the ones that are printed? This would indicate that you are not reading in the file you think you are.

Comment: Also note that if you use `delimiter=','`, but your file does not contain any comma, you cannot actually get the array out you report about. This means again that you are reading in a file that is not the one you think it is.

Comment: My bad. I'll edit. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes the values are different bc I didn't show you my actual file for the sake of being speedy. I will update to show the actual csv file that I have. A csv file should contain commas right?

Comment: The file reads correctly, except for the first value, zero. I'm stumped as to why -- when I change the first value to something else, say 50, I still get `nan`.

Comment: This is the output I get when running your program: `[  0.  58. 103. 345. 398. 427.]`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that's very odd.. My file now is exactly as mentioned above and I'm still getting `nan`. One solution I came up with is changing `0.00` to `00.00`. However excel doesn't do this automatically when I save as .csv so what is the underlying issue as to why it can't understand `0.00` as zero?

Comment: One thing you might still do is to upload the file to some place where people can test the actual file.

Comment: Check for invisible characters.

Comment: Check the file for a [byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  Inspect the first, say, four characters of the file.  You can do that outside of python with a program such as `hexdump`, or in python you can run: `with open('drift.csv', 'rb') as f: start = f.read(4); print(start.hex())`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser this solved the issue, there was an invisible byte-order mark in front of the zero, for some reason! Thanks!